# Proof Verification: Two problems from Elementary Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

> 1. Draw all connected graphs of order $5$ in which the distance between every two distinct vertices is odd. Explain why you know that you have drawn all such graphs.
> 2. Let $P = (u = v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_k = v)$ be a $u − v$ geodesic in a connected graph $G$. Prove that $d(u, v_i) = i$ for each integer $i$ with $1 \le i \le k$.

**My attempts at solutions:**

1. A graph of order $5$ has $5$ vertices, so the distance between every two distinct vertices has to be $1$ or  $3$ or $5$. Every two vertices include adjacent ones as well. Adjacent vertices are connected with only one edge. That means we can draw only one connected graph with $5$ vertices.
2. Let $P$ be a $u - v $ geodesic in a connected graph $G$. Then the distance between $u$ and $v$ is the smallest length of any $u − v$ path in $G$ by definition. Hence $d(u, v_k) = k$ and no $u − v$ path of smaller length exists in $G$ . But by assumption $i$ is an integer with $1 \le i \le k$, so $d(u, v_i) = i$.

Are these correct?

Answer (score 1):

As for 1), it seems you got the right idea but what does "Every two vertices include adjacent ones as well." mean ?

My personal way of saying it would be : if you have two vertices $u, v$ at distance 3 or 5, 
then necessarily there's a vertex at distance 2 from $u$ on the shortest $u - v$ path (That's what point 2. says !).
So the only available odd distance is actually 1, which leaves only one possibility.

For 2), you might want to complete the proof by stating why you can't have $d(u, v_i) < i$, nor $d(u, v_i) > i$ for any $1 \leq i < k$.  That is, $d(u, v_k) = k$ by definition, but what about the other values of $i$.

Comment: If $(u, u_i) < i$, then we we get at least one extra vertex not connected to $u_i$ which makes $G$  disconnected. If $(u, u_i)> i$, then the path $u - u_i$ skips at least one extra vertex and thus disconnects $G$. Does that sound correct? By "Every two vertices include adjacent ones as well." I meant we should consider distances between every single vertex, including the adjacent ones. I guess that line wasnt that important :)

Comment: Ah sorry I'm not sure I understand your arguments.  Adding an extra vertex or skipping one don't imply disconnecting the graph.  What I can say is that for $v_i$, since you know there is a path $uv_1 \ldots u_i$, the distance $d(u, v_i)$ can't be more than $i$.  So $d(u, v_i) > i$ is not possible.  Now, if $d(u, v_i) < i$, what happens to $d(u, v_k)$ ?  Also, I'm not sure I understand how you deduce  only one graph on 5 vertices exists, even though it's true.  Maybe it just needs rephrasing.  But first, can you actually draw it ?